# How to lint the commit, rather than the working directory?

Tags: git, eslint, lint, pre-commit-hook

I have an annoying problem. We are running linting as a pre-commit hook. The problem is that it is linting the working directory rather than the actual commit. There are two problems with this:

1. Commit is bad, but linting passes.
   If you forget to stage your changes after fixing the linting issues, this is what happens.
2. Commit is good, but linting fails.
   I often have some debug code that I don't intend to commit. There is really no point in linting those changes and it's annoying to deal with.

Now, the question is how I can write a smarter pre-commit hook that lints the actual commit rather than the working directory, preferably without changing the working directory?

Comment: Lint the staged diff only.

Comment: Sounds edge-casey. Don't build processes that rely on pre-commit hooks. They're for convenience only and can be easily disabled. We use different branches to represent major releases of our product, and occasionally post bug fixes to old branches. Because we use the latest version of eslint, linting fails on branches based on older releases. We just push to the server using `--no-verify`, but our build process is much more robust and ensures that linting (with the correct version) passes before merging to release branches (via PR)

Comment: @JDB Jenkins will also run linting before the commit is merged to master, so the process doesn't rely on the pre-commit hook. Problem is that Jenkins is normally overloaded and it may take significant time before it actually runs. The pre-commit hook is good, because it gives much faster feedback and prevents unnecessary load on Jenkins.

Comment: Yeah, that's why we have the hooks... to prevent unnecessary builds that are just going to fail anyways. Are you running into this issue often, or is this more theoretical? Seems to me that regularly pushing commits that don't reflect your working directory is going to cause a range of issues (unit tests come to mind).

Answer (score 1):

This is in general pretty difficult.

The most straightforward method is to extract the index into a temporary directory.  This has some obvious drawbacks: in particular, ignored files that live in the work-tree do not get carried into the temporary directory.  Worse, the temporary directory has only *this* repository's files: any environment (submodules and/or superprojects, for instance) are not carried over.

Carrying these things over is possible but consumes, potentially, a lot of space and/or time.

Here's a simple method for taking the entire work-tree (including submodules) over to a temporary directory, then extracting the index contents atop it:

```
#! /bin/sh -e

tmpdir=$(mktemp -d)
trap "rm -rf $tmpdir" 0 1 2 3 15

# remainder assumes we are at top of work-tree, which is true in
# practice in git hooks, even if it is not documented anywhere.

# step 1: copy current tree to tmp dir
tar cf - . | (cd $tmpdir; tar xf -)

# step 2: extract current index to tmp dir
git --work-tree=$tmpdir checkout -- .

# step 3: run tests
... tests go here ...
```

For pre-commit hooks that would like to modify files (e.g., use [`gofmt`](https://blog.golang.org/go-fmt-your-code) or [`clang-format`](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangTools.html)), this messes with the general idea, since now the modified files are in a temporary directory that gets removed.

Comment: I'd recommend to use `rsync` or `cp -ap` instead of 2 `tar`s. Other than that — perfect answer!

Comment: Thanks. I haven't had time to try this yet. As soon as I've confirmed that it's working, I'll accept your answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
git stash push --keep-index --include-untracked

# do some linting/testing and stuff

git stash pop
```

**explanation:**

`git stash --include-untracked` --> grab all changes since last commit and put them in the stash (including untracked files dah!)

`--keep-index` --> but actually keep the indexed(staged) files in the working directory

So it turns your working directory into a faithful representation of the commit (besides gitignored files and some other edge cases).